# Testing html/css image on local from jfiddle

Tags: html, css

I wonder why this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/y2BtT/90/) from jsfiddle is not properly working when run on local?

I copied the code to test in local.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/css">
.btn {
    display: block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 22px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-right:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn {
    background: url("http://www.aidancotter.com/images/face.png") no-repeat -5px 0px;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style:none;
}
.menu {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
    background:#78a802;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:90px;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    line-height:30px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.menu ul li:hover .btn {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}
</script>
<title>Image Hover Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="btn">HOVER</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong? :( Can't seem to figure it out, I copied the code exactly as is to test it and study it.

Answer (score 7):

`<script type="text/css"></script>`

should be

`<style type="text/css"></style>`

[CSS Style-sheets](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss)

Comment: And change </script> to </style>

Comment: I have a follow up question. After studying the code, why is the image(face.jpg) the colored and uncolored smile are together in one .png file? 

And what does this code's for? `background-position: -5px -120px;` I  believe it's for the smile..

Comment: @abc123  One file is having 2 images, so the background image is within the box so moving it outside is not feasible like this. What you could do is position your image outside of the box and move it into it. For more stuff visit [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

Answer (score 0):

don't use script type="text/css"

use the style tags

that is the only difference I see

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.btn {
    display: block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 22px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-right:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn {
    background: url("http://www.aidancotter.com/images/face.png") no-repeat -5px 0px;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style:none;
}
.menu {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding:20px 0 0 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
    background:#78a802;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:90px;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    line-height:30px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
.menu ul li:hover .btn {
    background-position: -5px -120px;
}
</style>
<title>Image Hover Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="btn">HOVER</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: What if I have 2 separate images, 1 white smile and the other is the green one. Now, whenever I hover on the smile it will turn green, otherwise it is white..